# PHP launching a Windows application

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I want to launch a bat file or exe

I tried

```
system("C:\\PATH\\TO\\FOLDER\\script.bat")
system("CMD.EXE C:\\PATH\\TO\\FOLDER\\script.bat")
system("C:\\PATH\\TO\\FOLDER\\exefile.exe /S nameOfFileToCreate.txt")
system("CMD.EXE C:\\PATH\\TO\\FOLDER\\exefile.exe /S nameOfFileToCreate.txt")
system("START C:\\PATH\\TO\\FOLDER\\script.bat")
system("START C:\\PATH\\TO\\FOLDER\\exefile.exe /S nameOfFileToCreate.txt")
```

With START, I get this error message. The others attempts result in the page loading forever!

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> WshShell.Exec<br/><b>Description:</b> The system cannot find the file specified. ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php:95 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php(95): com->Exec('START C:\PROGRA...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 95
```

Comment: Note also that you may need to quote your path if it contains spaces (which I'm guessing it does, given the path reported in your error message). Something like: `system("start \"C:\\Path with spaces\\program.exe\"");`

Comment: I used the short path like C:\PROGRA~1\MICRO~2\ instead of the long path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the exec function:

https://www.php.net/function.exec

Comment: this didnt work. For whatever reason, I can't launch the app. I decided to create a simple VBS script and I restart the PC with PHP as a temp solution

Answer (score 0):

this didnt work. For whatever reason, I can't launch the app. I decided to create a simple VBS script and I restart the PC with PHP as a temp solution